# knowing type variable at runtime

Tags: c#

I want to be sure that parameter variable is of type Guid.

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
{
   // if id != Guid print error
}
```

I guess pretty basic question but I'm stuck here.

Thanks

Comment: What else could it be?  If someone tried to pass something in other than a `Guid` it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you mean by `id != Guid` - are you talking about _type_ or specific values?

Comment: @DStanley - In this case. But with a non sealed reference type, you could pass in an sub-type.

Comment: @user1765862 please could you tell me why you are doing? I'm not criticising rather I'm interested in understanding why you would think it can be different and what you would do about it. It could point to a hole in your design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, there is no chance that the passed in value is **not** a GUID.

The [`GUID` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.guid.aspx) is a value type - it can't be inherited. This means that only type the compiler will accept as an argument to this method is a `GUID`.

Answer (score 2):

It always will be. The compiler ensures it.

Writing a parameter as `Guid id` means that only a instance of type `Guid` or a sub-type of `Guid` can may be passed to the method. Any attempt to pass a parameter of any other type will result either in a compiler error or a run-time exception (if you attempted to invoke the method via reflection).

As others have pointed out, `Guid` is a `struct` and cannot have sub-types.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you don't really need to in this specific scenario, because the compile will ensure it.

However, in general, you would want to use `GetType()` and `typeof` to do this check.

```
if (id.GetType() != typeof(System.Guid))
{
    // Print Error
}
```